# How to correctly integrate PayPal's API with paypal payments pro?

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment

I just finished building a donation form on a client's website, which processes payments through PayPal's classic api. It works fine in Sandbox mode, but I'm getting a `10501 -  This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.` error.

I know that this error is caused by PayPal payments pro not being enabled on the account the API is trying to access. That is were I'm somewhat confused. The account I'm connecting this donation form to is subscribed to Paypal Payments Pro.

When I first encountered the `10501` error, I thought that PayPal may require myself to log in and enable the Payments Pro service. I found a "get started" button under the payments pro section of the site, but when I click it, I'm taken to a page which only provides a link to the API documentation.

I've never worked with PayPal's API before or launched a live paypal application. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

NOTES

- Just to make it clear, the PHP donation form DOES work in PayPal's sandbox mode
- I have acquired the correct API keys from the live account and I know for a fact that I did not mix up the live credentials with the sandbox.
- this donation form is on a website, not an mobile app (do I still need to register it as a paypal app?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times what happens is that PayPal enables the Virtual Terminal for you, but not the DoDirectPayment API.  I would just give them a call and let them know you have Pro, but your DDP calls are resulting in this error, and they can probably get it enabled for you.

It's also possible that your version of Pro requires you to use the PayFlow API instead of DoDirectPayment.  That's something they can tell you when you call them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realized that Debit Card payments via website were not enabled on the account. I've filled out the form to enable that feature. While that request is processing, do I need to create/register an app to use the Classic API on the website, or is that only for mobile development (android,  iOS, etc)?